# Jquery autocomplte in two input field with two different message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create two input field with placeholder by autocomplete. This two field has showing data form same source array. When data match its OK but when anyone can edit after selection then its remove filed data and showing  message for two different fields.I am trying to do that but I can't. If you want, you will remove unnecessary code for fix that. Thanks!

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Sakib00123/7jhdk00h/7/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div class="demo">
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" id="selLanguage" placeholder="test1"/>
    <span id="message1"></span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="selLanguage2" placeholder="test2"/>
   <span id="message2"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I couldnt get what you trying to say.